# Get value from a class' variable from another class python

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

**PROBLEM:**

I'm creating a GUI for my application with wx.Python, it freezes when
the processing button is pressed so I'm trying to execute a thread
with the processing code, it needs to take values from main class and
also set values from the thread to the main class. I've tried what I
have seen from other post but non of them work.

Tl;dr, need to get values and modify a value from ***class pls*** get from ***pNombre*** and modify ***modtext***

**GOAL:**

Class thread should take *randomName* from users imput in *class pls* and set value of *modtext*

```
class TestThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        #try to get value from variable in the pls class
        randomName = self.pNombre.GetValue()
        
        for i in range (0,100):
           #this should modify modtext in pls class
           self.modtext.SetValue(str(i))

class pls(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'lilcode', size=(800, 600), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')

    mylist = ['2', '3']
    scene = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, 'pick', 'pick', mylist)
    if scene.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:

        if escena.GetStringSelection() == "2":
            self.pNombre = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style = wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, pos=(240,40), size=(300, 20))
            self.pNombre.SetFocus()
            my_sizer.Add(self.pNombre, 0, wx.CENTER)

            self.modtext = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style = wx.TE_READONLY, pos = (50, 280), size = (700, 23))

            start = wx.Button(panel, label="process", pos = (350, 220), size=(70, 23))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.initiate2d, start)
            panel.SetSizer(my_sizer)
            self.Show()

    def initiate2d(self, event):

        TestThread()
```

Comment: You need to describe specifically what the problem is. Saying what your goal is then just dumping code isn't exceedingly helpful.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon done.

Comment: If you want to post the solution to your own question, it is best if you post it as an answer, rather than editing the question to include the answer. SO allows you to self answer. I speak from experience, having made the same mistake myself with my first question. You may also accept your own answer, although it will not gain you any reputation points.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I have to read every rule there is for these post, it seems like I do nothing but lose reputation everytime I ask anything.

Comment: Au Contraire! +1  As long as you get answers to your questions, which enables you to move forward, does it really matter? Persevere and put thought into your questions and answers and reputation points will accrue, whether you want them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a thread inside the same class as a function that is called when a button is clicked

There is no need of creating another class...

```
class pls(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'lilcode', size=(800, 600), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')

    mylist = ['2', '3']
    scene = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, 'pick', 'pick', mylist)
    if scene.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:

        if escena.GetStringSelection() == "2":
            self.pNombre = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style = wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, pos=(240,40), size=(300, 20))
            self.pNombre.SetFocus()
            my_sizer.Add(self.pNombre, 0, wx.CENTER)

            self.modtext = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style = wx.TE_READONLY, pos = (50, 280), size = (700, 23))

            start = wx.Button(panel, label="process", pos = (350, 220), size=(70, 23))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.initiate2da, start)
            panel.SetSizer(my_sizer)
            self.Show()

    def initiate2d(self):

        for i in range (0,100):
           #this should modify modtext in pls class
           self.modtext.SetValue(str(i))
    def initiate2da(self, event):
        threading.Thread(target = self.initiate2d).start()
```